# is it possible to use GORM with Spring Data JPA and Rest?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm a little bit new to the "Groovy world" and I just started to work with the language to understand syntax and characteristics. Previously I worked a lot with Java and Spring Boot and since the last one is supported by Pivotal as much as Groovy and Grails are, I wondered if it's possible to use Groovy w/o issues with Spring Boot.

Well it works (obviously), but when I discovered the syntax of GORM and the DSL around of it I started to use it. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to fit well with Spring Data JPA and Rest, since I tried to do something like this:

```
@grails.persistence.Entity
class Person {
    BigInteger id
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static mapping { table name: 'people' }
    static constraints { /* whatever */ }
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "/api/people")
interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, BigInteger> { }
```

However Spring Boot is not able to run since it throws an exception with the following statement

```
IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed bean Person
```

On the other side if I fix that Entity with JPA annotations (by removing the annotation of Grails then), I've got no issues at all.

Is there any solution on this? Is it possible to use GORM somehow with Spring Data JPA and Rest, since GORM is relying on Hibernate anyway?

Comment: after some research I found it's not possible to use GORM in the way I wanted, since Grails is not totally compatible with Spring Boot and I need to wait for the version 3.0 of it. Infact the next version of Grails will be based on Spring Boot (as far as I understand), so I need to be patient :)

Comment: Is this now possible with grails3?

Comment: Frankly I didn't try yet, since I totally give up on Groovy, not because of GORM or something else, but for the Pivotal decision to do not support the language anymore. This has slowed down the development of it a lot and still there's no news about a complete Java 8 support (default methods, lambda - yeah I know Groovy has closure, but it's not the same -, etc...). Subjective decision. Anyway if you really need GORM just use Grails 3 since it is developed on Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define property **hibernate.packages** in your **application.properties** or **application.yml** with path to package with entities. Sample:

```
database:
  driver: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/retail
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
hibernate:
  packages: ru.rd.core.analytic.dto.jpa
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
  show_sql: true
  hbm2ddl.auto: validate #none validate create-drop update
```